# create an extension (android application) for mobile firefox (fennec)

Tags: android, firefox-addon, fennec

I want create an extension for fennec (mobile firefox) in android, i have already an android application and i want lunch it from mobile firefox, by tapping a button that i will add to the user interface of this web browser, I did a lot of research but I'm still lost, I do not know where to start .. if any one has a link to tutorials or good documentation, please give it to me

Thanks a lot in advance for any help !

Comment: What exactly are you asking, a tutorial for Firefox Mobile extensions or how to launch an Android app from inside the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Use nsIProcess.

Examples:
https://ask.mozilla.org/question/301/open-firefox-profile-with-nsiprocess-and-access-it-via-privealaged-scope/

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess

Comment: bsIProcess will not launch Android apps.

Comment: Hi there I noticed you accepted this as bounty, can you please show us the code on how you got it to work.

Comment: @paa would using js-ctypes and popen or something do the trick?

Comment: No. Ask a new question for the answer.